# Referencing media from theme settings and display it on front page

Tags: 8, theming, media

In a custom subtheme of classy base theme, I made a theme setting for referencing an image media file. Contents of file theme-settings.php:

```
<?php
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeSettings;
use Drupal\system\Form\ThemeSettingsForm;
use Drupal\Core\Form;
function mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {

$opts = [
'#type'          => 'entity_autocomplete',
'#title'         => t("Image on startpage"),
'#description'   => t("Referencing an image."),
'#target_type'   => 'media',
'#selection_settings' => ['target_bundles' => ['image']],
];
if ($default_id = theme_get_setting('startpage_image')) {
// element stores an int ID, but default value has to be the loaded entity
$image = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('media')->load($default_id);
$opts['#default_value'] = $image;
}
$form['startpage_image'] = $opts;
}
?>
```

Contents of file mytheme.theme:

```
<?php

function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
$media_id = theme_get_setting('startpage_image');
$media = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('media')->load($media_id);
$variables['media_build'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('media')->view($media, 'media.full');
}

?>
```

And finally in the template `page--front.html.twig` the image is called by `{{ startpage_image }}`. But unfortunately, the image isn't shown (all caches rebuilt and flushed multiple times). In the last line in file mytheme.theme I also tried `view($media, 'full')` because I wasn't sure if `media.full` is the correct display mode that is built in into media core module — but this as well wasn't successfull.

Why is my code not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should add a test to see if it's the homepage or not, using

```
\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()
```

Then if you add a variables in your `hook_page` for exemple `$variables['media_build']` you could get in the twig with `{{ media_build }}`.

Comment: Thank you, now it's working!